# Porque sumiram minhas perguntas antigas?

Tags: suporte

Ola, boa tarde,

A bastante tempo atrás... a uns 5 anos, eu tinha uma reputação aqui no stackoverflow, acho que no site em inglês.

Agora sumiram minhas perguntas e respostas antigas.

Tem como recuperar ?
Grato

Comment: Seria esta conta? http://stackoverflow.com/users/2204340/helderam

Comment: Sim! Encontrei um e-mail antigo.

Comment: Lembrando que os pontos em cada site da rede são separados mesmo. Seus pontos do Stack Overflow continuarão separados dos pontos do Stack Overflow em Português, do Portuguese Language, SuperUser e quaisquer sites que tenha perfil. A mesclagem é uma conveniência adequada para unificar as notificações e todo o resto que não envolva reputação e medalhas.

Comment: Obrigado pessoal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você tem que pedir para mesclar as duas contas.

Sugiro escrever no perfil de cada conta que deseja mesclar com a outra para provar que você tem controle sobre as duas contas.

Depois entre em contato com a equipe em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact